# Having trouble using Pandas to chain multiple statements together

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to filter multiple columns out of an excel spreadsheet to simplify some tasks at my work. This was the solution I thought would work the best without having to write and rewrite a file multiple times.
I am pretty sure it has something to do with the variables before the bigsplit variable. I also tried with or without the parenthesis surrounding and inside the bigsplit variable.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
file = "07-14-2020.xlsx"
df=pd.read_excel(file)
    disco2=df[df["Discontinued"] == 'N']
    close2=df[df["Store Closeout"] == 'N']
    oi2=df[df["Order Indicator+"] != 'S']
    dropship2=df[df["Primary Vendor"] == 'VENDOR']
    
    bigsplit = (df[(disco2) & (close2) & (oi2) & (dropship2)]) <--Error here
```

Using the (&) operators and (and) operators gives me the errors below.

The Error when using AND:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The Error when using &:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
```

Comment: Not 100% sure without sample data, but `disco2`, for example, is **not** a Boolean mask (it's a DataFrame) as you have already subset the DataFrame (`df[that_Boolean_mask]`). Instead I'm guessing you want to define stuff as `disco2 = df["Discontinued"] == 'N'` and then your `bigsplit` will work.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did fix the errors I was having. But I am a little confused on the why. When I use the mask(which I believe is 'code' df[df["Discontinued"] == 'N'] 'code' correct me if I'm wrong) I use this mask in other variables in previous sections of my code and allow me to save the variable to a new excel. Would it be easier or cleaner to get rid of the mask for other variables? For example my 'code' disco1 'code' is 'code' disco1 = df[df["Discontinued"] == 'Y']'code' but I save that directly to a spreadsheet without splitting further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want

```
disco2 = df["Discontinued"] == 'N'
close2 = df["Store Closeout"] == 'N'
oi2 = df["Order Indicator+"] != 'S'
dropship2 = df["Primary Vendor"] == 'VENDOR'
    
bigsplit = df[disco2 & close2 & oi2 & dropship2]
```

Here we get **boolean** Series which can be combined with `&`.
In you original code you make `df` slices. Error says it isn't clear how to get boolean value out of a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This does fix the issue and my code is running exactly how I wanted now. A follow up question if you will. When should I use df slices and when should I not? For example, I am using ` disco1=df[df["Discontinued"] == 'Y'] ` for my ` disco1 ` variable. Then saving using

 ` writer=pd.ExcelWriter('Split_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
disco.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Disco')`

Is this not necessary?